# How to interrupt a thread which is waiting for std::condition_variable_any in C++?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, interrupt

I'm reading C++ concurrency in action.
It introduces how to implement interrupting thread using std::condition_variable_any.
I try to understand the code more than a week, but I couldn't.

Below is the code and explanation in the book.

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class thread_interrupted : public std::exception {};

class interrupt_flag {
  std::atomic<bool> flag;
  std::condition_variable* thread_cond;
  std::condition_variable_any* thread_cond_any;
  std::mutex set_clear_mutex;

 public:
  interrupt_flag() : thread_cond(0), thread_cond_any(0) {}
  void set() {
    flag.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(set_clear_mutex);
    if (thread_cond) {
      thread_cond->notify_all();
    } else if (thread_cond_any) {
      thread_cond_any->notify_all();
    }
  }

  bool is_set() const { return flag.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); }
  template <typename Lockable>
  void wait(std::condition_variable_any& cv, Lockable& lk);
};

thread_local static interrupt_flag this_thread_interrupt_flag;

void interruption_point() {
  if (this_thread_interrupt_flag.is_set()) {
    throw thread_interrupted();
  }
}

template <typename Lockable>
void interrupt_flag::wait(std::condition_variable_any& cv, Lockable& lk) {
  struct custom_lock {
    interrupt_flag* self;

    // (1) What is this lk for? Why is lk should be already locked when it is used in costume_lock constructor?
    Lockable& lk;     
    custom_lock(interrupt_flag* self_, std::condition_variable_any& cond,
                Lockable& lk_)
        : self(self_), lk(lk_) {
      self->set_clear_mutex.lock();
      self->thread_cond_any = &cond;
    }
    void unlock() {
      lk.unlock();
      self->set_clear_mutex.unlock();
    }
    void lock() { std::lock(self->set_clear_mutex, lk); }
    ~custom_lock() {
      self->thread_cond_any = 0;
      self->set_clear_mutex.unlock();
    }
  };
  custom_lock cl(this, cv, lk);
  interruption_point();
  cv.wait(cl);
  interruption_point();
}

class interruptible_thread {
  std::thread internal_thread;
  interrupt_flag* flag;

 public:
  template <typename FunctionType>
  interruptible_thread(FunctionType f) {
    std::promise<interrupt_flag*> p;
    internal_thread = std::thread([f, &p] {
      p.set_value(&this_thread_interrupt_flag);
      f();
    });

    flag = p.get_future().get();
  }

  void interrupt() {
    if (flag) {
      flag->set();
    }
  };

  void join() { internal_thread.join(); };
  void detach();
  bool joinable() const;
};

template <typename Lockable>
void interruptible_wait(std::condition_variable_any& cv, Lockable& lk) {
  this_thread_interrupt_flag.wait(cv, lk);
}

void foo() {

  // (2) This is my implementation of how to use interruptible wait. Is it correct?
  std::condition_variable_any cv;
  std::mutex m;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
  try {
    interruptible_wait(cv, lk);
  } catch (...) {
    std::cout << "interrupted" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  interruptible_thread th(foo);
  th.interrupt();
  th.join();
}
```

> Your custom lock type acquires the lock on the internal
> set_clear_mutex when it’s constructed 1, and then sets the
> thread_cond_any pointer to refer to the std:: condition_variable_any
> passed in to the constructor 2.
>
> The Lockable reference is stored for later; this must already be
> locked. You can now check for an interruption without worrying about
> races. If the interrupt flag is set at this point, it was set before
> you acquired the lock on set_clear_mutex. When the condition variable
> calls your unlock() function inside wait(), you unlock the Lockable
> object and the internal set_clear_mutex 3.
>
> This allows threads that are trying to interrupt you to acquire the
> lock on set_clear_mutex and check the thread_cond_any pointer once
> you’re inside the wait() call but not before. This is exactly what you
> were after (but couldn’t manage) with std::condition_variable.
>
> Once wait() has finished waiting (either because it was notified or
> because of a spurious wake), it will call your lock() function, which
> again acquires the lock on the internal set_clear_mutex and the lock
> on the Lockable object 4. You can now check again for interruptions
> that happened during the wait() call before clearing the
> thread_cond_any pointer in your custom_lock destructor 5, where you
> also unlock the set_clear_mutex.

First, I couldn't understand what is the purpose of `Lockabel& lk` in mark (1) and why it is already locked in constructor of custom_lock. (It could be locked in the very custom_lock constructor. )

Second there is no example in this book of how to use interruptible wait, so `foo() {}` in mark (2) is my guess implementation of how to use it. Is it correct way of using it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need a mutex-like object (lk in your foo function) to call the interruptiple waiting just as you would need it for the plain std::condition_variable::wait function.

What's problematic (I also read the book and I have doubts about this example) is that the flag member points to a memory location inside the other thread which could finish right before calling flag->set(). In this specific example the thread only exists after we set the flag so that is okay, but otherwise this approach is limited in my opinion (correct me if I am wrong).